# Java True Global Variables (Eclipse for Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, variables

This should be relatively straight forward however I'm being swamped in SQL information whenever I search for help with this.

Basically I have 3 classes and they each generate a number and I want to get the total number at the end. Is there a way to make a variable which all 3 classes can add to without generating a SQLite Database?

example

- Page1.java creates 5  -> adds to Total
- Page2.java creates 12 -> adds to Total
- Page3.java creates 10 -> adds to Total
- Page4.java opens total

Like I said, its likely a simple problem but SQLite is dominating my searches.

Hope you can help, Thanks.

Comment: What is your context here? Are they running within the same app? Can instances of the 3 classes be accessed from a common place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a static variable for that.
If you don't care about encapsulation you could even use one single public static variable for this purpose.

Example:

```
private static int mCounter = 0;

public static void addToCounter(int i)
{
    mCounter += i;
}

public static int getCount()
{
    return mCounter;
}
```

Comment: Eclipse has a problem with every thing and it's fix is to rename everything so nothing is linked. I am still getting to grips with Java and i have no idea how i could implement this over multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do would be to have a private value, say, `private int count` in each of your class and its respective getter. You would then also have a method in each class, say, `public void doSomething(){... count = ...}`.

Once you have all these, in `Page4` you could do something like:

public class Page4
{
     Page1 pg1 = new Page1();
     Page2 pg2 = new Page2();
     Page3 pg3 = new Page3();

```
 pg1.doSomething();
 pg2.doSomething();
 pg3.doSomething();

 int total = pg1.getCount() + pg2.getCount() + pg3.getCount();
```

}

On the other hand, you could pass in an integer variable to the class which gets modified and passed on to the next class.

You could also pass in a reference to some class which contains the actual counter, and once that each class (`Page1`, `Page2`...) has finished doing what it needs it would simply reference that class and update the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that clear how you call your classes.

However if you have just 3 simple classes and one place to call the classes you could pass your variable between the classes and add the values to it.

```
public class Page1 {

  public void addToVariable(int var) {
    var = var + 5;
  }
}

public class Page2 {

  public void addToVariable(int var) {
    var = var + 12;
  }
}
...
```

And then call the class methods with your variable:

```
int yourVariable = 0;
Page1 p1 = new Page1();
Page2 p2 = new Page2();

p1.addToVariable(yourVariable);
p2.addToVariable(yourVariable);
```

`yourVariable` will hold the total you're looking for.